# Why IAsyncEnumerator doesn't have the Reset method in C#8?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-8.0

Why IAsyncEnumerator doesn't have the Reset method ? It only has the Current property and the MoveNextAsync() method.

```
public interface IAsyncEnumerator<out T> : IAsyncDisposable
{
    T Current
    {
        get;
    }

    ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it should have? I don't see it mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Even in "normal" IEnumerables they are rarely used. In fact, in all my years I never saw anybody using the Reset method. I guess it being a virtually unknown and unused feature may have had a hand in the decision to not include it.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for [`IEnumerator.Reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a NotSupportedException.

It's very very rare to find a `Reset` method which does anything other than throw an exception. All of the Linq types throw (e.g. [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,114)), and compiler-generated IEnumerators throw as well (see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGALAbgFgAoFAZiwCYMBhDAbxI2awpzIB4c0A+DAWQAUASgZMWEnNiwB2DACIo8osQkBfEmqA==)).

Given that `IAsyncEnumerator` is never going to interop with COM, and given that there won't be any C# code in the wild which relies on being able to `Reset` an IEnumerator, why bother adding a similar method to `IAsyncEnumerator` which will likewise always be implemented by throwing an exception?